Why was && chosen as rvalue reference in C++?
I am NOT asking what && means.
Does anyone know the history of why the symbol && was chosen? I can give some guesses, but wondering about the actual history. I know lot's of stuff is discussed through the mailing list. However I'm having trouble finding the history on this. Seems like discussions started in 2006.
All I've found is from here:

The '&&' is the token which identifies the reference as an "rvalue reference" (bindable to an rvalue) and distinguishes it from our current reference syntax.
But this does not explain the reasoning behind the symbol choice.

Note I already asked this here, but looks like it was the wrong site.

Probably because & prefix is already associated with references, and && was not otherwised used in this context (its other meaning is logical AND, which can't be used in declarations).

@Barmar Binary && can appear in array sizes and template parameters. Still, unary && doesn't introduce any issues that * and & didn't.

if you were the designer, what would you have chosen instead?
